# Check if a value exists per group and remove groups without this value in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'value1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 'value2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Per group in column `value1` I would like to check if that group contains at least one value 'C' in column `value2`. If a group doesn't have a 'C' value, I would like to exclude that group

```
    value1  value2
    1       A
    1       B
    1       C
    2       C
    3       A
    3       B
    4       B
    4       A
    4       A
    4       B
```

The resulting df should look like this:

```
    value1  value2
    1       A
    1       B
    1       C
    2       C
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want something efficient: `df[df['value1'].isin(df['value2'].eq('C').groupby(df['value1']).any().loc[lambda s: s].index)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `groupby filter`

```
df.groupby('value1').filter(lambda x: x['value2'].eq('C').sum() > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

- First establish a list containing the `value1` values for which `value2` is equal to `C`: `mylist = df[df.value2=='C']['value1'].unique()`
- Then filter the dataframe `df`, keeping only rows for which `value1` is in this list: `df[df.value1.isin(mylist)]`.

Or as a one-liner:

`df[df.value1.isin(df[df.value2=='C']['value1'].unique())]`